# re: Error on Google BigQueryJavaGettingStarted

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to Google bigquery , and I just tried to run the Google BigQueryJavaGettingStarted, but I am having problems. It gave me error messages saying that "The method setDataStoreFactory(FileDataStoreFactory) is undefined for the type GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder", and "The method load(JsonFactory, InputStream) in the type GoogleClientSecrets is not applicable for the arguments (JacksonFactory, Reader)". I could not figure out why it gave me such errors since I have import all the spcific jar files from the tutorial to my project. So any ideas on how to fix these errors would be greatly appreciated.

Many Thanks in advance for all of your help.

Below is my simple program from Google BigQueryJavaGettingStarted

```
package com.google.cloud.bigquery.samples;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.java6.auth.oauth2.AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp;
import com.google.api.client.extensions.jetty.auth.oauth2.LocalServerReceiver;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleClientSecrets;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleTokenResponse;

import com.google.api.client.util.store.DataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.store.FileDataStoreFactory;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.http.javanet.NetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Datasets;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.Bigquery.Jobs.Insert;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.BigqueryScopes;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.DatasetList;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.GetQueryResultsResponse;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.Job;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobConfiguration;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobConfigurationQuery;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.JobReference;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableCell;
import com.google.api.services.bigquery.model.TableRow;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;
public class BigQueryJavaGettingStarted {

 private static final String PROJECT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "/path/to/your/client_secret.json";



  static GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = loadClientSecrets();

    // Static variables for API scope, callback URI, and HTTP/JSON functions
  private static final List<String> SCOPES = Arrays.asList(BigqueryScopes.BIGQUERY);
  private static final String REDIRECT_URI = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob";

  /** Global instances of HTTP transport and JSON factory objects. */
  private static final HttpTransport TRANSPORT = new NetHttpTransport();
  private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = new JacksonFactory();

  private static GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = null;

    /** Directory to store user credentials. */
  private static final java.io.File DATA_STORE_DIR =
      new java.io.File(System.getProperty("user.home"), ".store/bq_sample");

  /**
   * Global instance of the {@link DataStoreFactory}. The best practice is to make it a single
   * globally shared instance across your application.
   */
  private static FileDataStoreFactory dataStoreFactory;

  /**
   * @param args
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws InterruptedException
   */
  public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // Create a new BigQuery client authorized via OAuth 2.0 protocol
    // dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    Bigquery bigquery = createAuthorizedClient();

    // Print out available datasets in the "publicdata" project to the console
    listDatasets(bigquery, "publicdata");

    // Start a Query Job
    String querySql = "SELECT TOP(word, 50), COUNT(*) FROM publicdata:samples.shakespeare";
    JobReference jobId = startQuery(bigquery, PROJECT_ID, querySql);

    // Poll for Query Results, return result output
    Job completedJob = checkQueryResults(bigquery, PROJECT_ID, jobId);

    // Return and display the results of the Query Job
    displayQueryResults(bigquery, PROJECT_ID, completedJob);

  }

  /** Authorizes the installed application to access user's protected data. */
  private static Credential authorize() throws IOException {
    dataStoreFactory = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
    // set up authorization code flow
    GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(
        dataStoreFactory).build();
    // authorize
    return new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
  }

  /**
   * Creates an authorized BigQuery client service using the OAuth 2.0 protocol
   *
   * This method first creates a BigQuery authorization URL, then prompts the
   * user to visit this URL in a web browser to authorize access. The
   * application will wait for the user to paste the resulting authorization
   * code at the command line prompt.
   *
   * @return an authorized BigQuery client
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static Bigquery createAuthorizedClient() throws IOException {

    Credential credential = authorize();
    return new Bigquery(TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential);
  }

  /**
   * Display all BigQuery datasets associated with a project
   *
   * @param bigquery  an authorized BigQuery client
   * @param projectId a string containing the current project ID
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static void listDatasets(Bigquery bigquery, String projectId)
      throws IOException {
    Datasets.List datasetRequest = bigquery.datasets().list(projectId);
    DatasetList datasetList = datasetRequest.execute();
    if (datasetList.getDatasets() != null) {
      List<DatasetList.Datasets> datasets = datasetList.getDatasets();
      System.out.println("Available datasets\n----------------");
      System.out.println(datasets.toString());
      for (DatasetList.Datasets dataset : datasets) {
        System.out.format("%s\n", dataset.getDatasetReference().getDatasetId());
      }
    }
  }

  /**
   * Creates a Query Job for a particular query on a dataset
   *
   * @param bigquery  an authorized BigQuery client
   * @param projectId a String containing the project ID
   * @param querySql  the actual query string
   * @return a reference to the inserted query job
   * @throws IOException
   */
  public static JobReference startQuery(Bigquery bigquery, String projectId,
                                        String querySql) throws IOException {
    System.out.format("\nInserting Query Job: %s\n", querySql);

    Job job = new Job();
    JobConfiguration config = new JobConfiguration();
    JobConfigurationQuery queryConfig = new JobConfigurationQuery();
    config.setQuery(queryConfig);

    job.setConfiguration(config);
    queryConfig.setQuery(querySql);

    Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, job);
    insert.setProjectId(projectId);
    JobReference jobId = insert.execute().getJobReference();

    System.out.format("\nJob ID of Query Job is: %s\n", jobId.getJobId());

    return jobId;
  }

  /**
   * Polls the status of a BigQuery job, returns Job reference if "Done"
   *
   * @param bigquery  an authorized BigQuery client
   * @param projectId a string containing the current project ID
   * @param jobId     a reference to an inserted query Job
   * @return a reference to the completed Job
   * @throws IOException
   * @throws InterruptedException
   */
  private static Job checkQueryResults(Bigquery bigquery, String projectId, JobReference jobId)
      throws IOException, InterruptedException {
    // Variables to keep track of total query time
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long elapsedTime;

    while (true) {
      Job pollJob = bigquery.jobs().get(projectId, jobId.getJobId()).execute();
      elapsedTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
      System.out.format("Job status (%dms) %s: %s\n", elapsedTime,
          jobId.getJobId(), pollJob.getStatus().getState());
      if (pollJob.getStatus().getState().equals("DONE")) {
        return pollJob;
      }
      // Pause execution for one second before polling job status again, to
      // reduce unnecessary calls to the BigQUery API and lower overall
      // application bandwidth.
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
  }

  /**
   * Makes an API call to the BigQuery API
   *
   * @param bigquery     an authorized BigQuery client
   * @param projectId    a string containing the current project ID
   * @param completedJob to the completed Job
   * @throws IOException
   */
  private static void displayQueryResults(Bigquery bigquery,
                                          String projectId, Job completedJob) throws IOException {
    GetQueryResultsResponse queryResult = bigquery.jobs()
        .getQueryResults(
            projectId, completedJob
            .getJobReference()
            .getJobId()
        ).execute();
    List<TableRow> rows = queryResult.getRows();
    System.out.print("\nQuery Results:\n------------\n");
    for (TableRow row : rows) {
      for (TableCell field : row.getF()) {
      System.out.printf("%-50s", field.getV());
       }
      System.out.println();
    }
  }

  /**
   * Helper to load client ID/Secret from file.
   *
   * @return a GoogleClientSecrets object based on a clientsecrets.json
   */
  private static GoogleClientSecrets loadClientSecrets() {
    try {
      InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION);
        Reader reader =
          new InputStreamReader(inputStream);
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(new JacksonFactory(),
                reader);
        return clientSecrets;
    } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println("Could not load client secrets file " + CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION);
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
  }



}
```

Comment: Could you paste those errors to the question?

Comment: I understand you wouldn't disclose your personal information, but just doublechecking that you notice these variables must be set: "private static final String PROJECT_ID = "xxxxxxxxxxxx";
  private static final String CLIENTSECRETS_LOCATION = "/path/to/your/client_secret.json";"

Answer (score 0):

The maven pom.xml file misses a reference to two dependencies:

```
com.google.oauth-client % google-oauth-client-java7 % 1.16.0-rc
com.google.oauth-client % google-auth-client-jetty % 1.19.0
```